# Нахождение максимального и минимального значений

Tags: python

Предложите более простой способ нахождения максимального и минимального чисел из заданных, БЕЗ использования функций `min()` и `max()`.

В моем коде задается 6 чисел (первое - первая строчка и еще 5 в цикле `for`) и из них выбираются максимальное и минимальное. Заранее спасибо.

Мой способ:

```
a=float(input('enter number '))
'''создание первого числа'''

min = a
max = a
'''присвоение значения первого числа максимальному и минимальному значению'''

for i in range(5):
    '''цикл для создания чисел и проверки их на максимальность или минимальность'''

    a=float(input('enter number '))
    '''создание нового числа'''

    if a > max:
        '''проверка на максимальность'''
        max = a

    if a < max and a < min:
        '''проверка на минимальность'''
        min = a

print('\n','min is: ',round(min,2),'\n','max is: ',round(max,2))
'''вывод миниального и максимального чисел'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш алгоритм проще не сделать - чтобы узнать минимум/максимум, в любом случае нужно сравнить все числа.

Но код можно немного упростить:

1. В модуле sys есть информация о максимальном и минимальном значении типа float, конкретно в `sys.float_info`, можно использовать это, чтобы не присваивать значение первого введенного числа.
2. Также не совсем понятно, для чего вы делаете лишнюю проверку `a < max` при проверке числа на минимальность. Если число меньше минимума, то оно, очевидно, меньше максимума, ведь переменная максимума в вашем коде только растет, а переменная минимума только убывает, если изначально они равны, то проверка `a < max` всегда будет выдавать True, а значит, она лишняя.

   ```
   import sys

   min = sys.float_info.max
   max = sys.float_info.min

   for i in range(6):
       a = float(input('enter number '))

       if a > max:
           max = a

       if a < min:
           min = a

   print('\n', 'min is: ', round(min,2), '\n', 'max is: ', round(max,2))
   ```

Comment: минимальное целое из двух значений можно найти без сравнения вообще:

`sub ebx, eax
sbb ecx, ecx
and ecx, ebx
add eax, ecx`

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать **отсортировать** список и взять первое и последнее значение, примерно вот так:

```
>>> my_list = [1, 23, 45, 1.5, 0, -4]
>>> my_list.sort()
>>> print (my_list)
[-4, 0, 1, 1.5, 23, 45]

>>> max = my_list.pop()
>>> print (max)
45

>>> min= my_list[0]
>>> print (min)
-4
```

Comment: Я думал о реализации с помощью списков, но мне хотелось сделать это без их помощи, но все равно приму к сведению ваш способ.

Comment: Автор вроде бы искал более "простой" способ, раз уж мы и так проходим по всем значениям, зачем нам делать это второй раз для сортировки, если сама сортировка нам не нужна? Да и сортировка, к тому же, медленнее, чем линейный поиск.

Comment: У автора сложность `O(n)`, у вас - `O(n log n)` - я бы не назвал это улучшением..., хотя код выглядит проще

Comment: Согласен на счет скорости, но когда вопрос идет о 6 значениях - нет разницы как искать значение.

Comment: Так вопрос был "более простой способ нахождения максимального и минимального чисел из заданных", без конкретных размеров, более того, оригинальный код автора не хранит данные в памяти, что при больших значениях размера списка скажется. Допустим, сюда придет новый человек с таким же вопросом, но значений у него будет 1кк, он увидит ваш код и подумает, что так и надо :)